# How to increase/decrease decimal places using AppleScript in Excel for Mac (v2015)

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I am looking for the same functionality as the ribbon buttons that adjust the number of decimal places shown for the selected range, so 'increase by one' or 'decrease by one.'

https://www.evernote.com/l/AApXNJsEcZlM26TNTsHN1FSwP3eUTuJJwqU

Comment: Did you check the Excel dictionary?

Comment: I have not and frankly I'm not sure what that means. I'm very well versed in VB for Excel and Excel itself, but all my work to date has been on Windows and now on OSX. I would appreciate you pointing me to a resource for this or on how to peel back the hood on Excel for Mac.

Comment: In the File menu of the Script Editor select "Open Dictionary..." and it will present all application script dictionary. Each dictionary contains the types and events that you can use for your script to interface with the application.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! Still can't find exactly what I am looking for but will keep looking.

Comment: Any luck with the dictionary?

Comment: No luck, I found these two, which looked applicable, but could not figure out how to use them in an actual script. Any thoughts? https://www.evernote.com/l/AAppi-VpQItGbIB6fXtdLXwna49HUjULfXM

Comment: I don't have 2015 (2011) but I will take a look at the dictionary. I don't know how much has changed between the versions but it sounds like the functionality is still there in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

rkp333

Try the following as this works in prior versions (2011) of Excel:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
   tell sheet 1
       tell cell 1 of used range
           set number format to "0.00" -- can be 0,00 in some localizations
       end tell
   end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Frank, thanks for looking into this. I actually have setting a specific number of places working. What I am trying to do it sequentially increase or decrease the number of decimal places for any formatted number. So:

Comment: "0.000" would become "0.0000" for increase, and the reverse for decrease.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having the parse the existing number format string as well, since I have no idea how to work with strings in AppleScript as well. And bc I want this to be general purpose and hopefully ride off of 'native' excel calls. If I could programatically click these buttons, that would serve my purpose as well: http://bit.ly/1L0mqsd

Comment: The code I posted was an example and it was meant to show you that you can, indeed, change the format. Can you edit your question to show a pseudo code of exactly what you are looking to do? As increases and decreases are easy enough with the string manipulation of AS.